# Ubuntu 18.04.3 High CPU Usage

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cpu, process, cpu-usage

**Update - Sorting by running `htop --sort PERCENT_CPU`**

[Snippet of processes running `htop --sort PERCENT_CPU`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S74Bs.png)

---

I have a Ubuntu 18.04.3 Droplet running on DigitalOcean.

The CPU seems to be at a constant ~100%.

I have tried the following to find out why:

- Running the `top` command

  `%Cpu(s):  0.0 us, 12.4 sy, 87.0 ni,  0.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st`

  - I noticed the `ni` process is running high
  - But can't see any high CPU in the Process Table - [Snippet of processes running`top`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZ7nM.png)
- Running the `htop` command

  - CPU seems high, but again I can't see anything obvious in the Process Table - [Snippet of processes running `htop`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJuky.png)

I have read the following tutorials:

- [How To Monitor CPU Use on DigitalOcean Droplets](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-monitor-cpu-use-on-digitalocean-droplets)
- [How To Use ps, kill, and nice to Manage Processes in Linux](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ps-kill-and-nice-to-manage-processes-in-linux)

This is a very small site with a single API.

Am I missing something or is there an underlying issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*Replying as answer since I can't comment*

If you sort by CPU usage with `htop --sort PERCENT_CPU` the process consuming your CPU time should be at the very top of the list (make sure you're running it as root [`sudo`] so you can see the information for all processes). If you update your question with what you see there we can help further.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, updated with a link to a snippet running `htop --sort PERCENT_CPU` (sorry I can't add images directly yet!)

Comment: Oh sorry that's my bad, I didn't realize those links here screenshots  It is worth noting that all that blue in the CPU graph is low priority workloads. I think that's indicative of your unused CPU resources being allocated to a noisy neighbor. Checking my facts now...

Comment: I can't find anything concrete about how DO go about stealing CPU. The fact that ni is so high but st is zero all while top shows nothing using excessive CPU perplexes me. I'm sorry I can't be of more help ☹

Comment: No worries, the screenshot links weren't obvious, just updated to hopefully make them clearer. It's confusing me too, but thanks for looking into it, much appreciated :-), I'll keep digging and see how we go!